# How does the control flow in a recursive program work?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I am not sure why this piece of code prints out "5678998765". I see how it gets the 56789 part but when the numbers start going down is where i get confused. So if someone could explain i would be grateful.

```
int out(int k) {

    if (k == 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d", k);
    out(k +1);
    printf("%d", k);
}


int main()
{
    out(5);
    return 0;
```

Comment: It prints each digit twice: once on the way in and again on the way out. For example, when `9`  is printed `out(9+1)` doesn't do anything, and the next `9` is printed immediately. The other digits' outputs are separated by whatever happens in between, during the recursion.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: This is the sequence -> `print(5) -> recursive(6) -> print(6) -> ... print(9) -> recursive(9) -> return 1 -> print(9) -> return void -> print(8) -> return void -> print(7) ->return void ->  print(6) ->return void ->  print(5) -> return void`. The second print is never called until the recursion is finished, and then start printing top to bottum. BTW, although it works, you should return an int value because your function is of type `int`. Though it can be void.

Comment: What did you expect? "5678999999" ? or just "56789"

Comment: ...so the number are not "getting smaller". They are the same as they were when printed the first time, like 56**7**8998**7**65.

Answer (score 1):

It is printed from last `printf`; every function needs to be executed till the end.

```
int out(int k) {

    if (k == 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    printf(" + %d", k);
    out(k +1);
    printf(" - %d", k);
}
```

You should try this, when it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Within the function for each value of `k` that is not equal to `10` there are two calls of `printf`

```
printf("%d", k);
out(k +1);
printf("%d", k);
```

So if the function is called the first time when k is equal to 5 then you will have

```
5 ( a call of out( 6 ) ) 5
```

then in the recursive call you will heav

```
56 ( a call of out( 7 ) ) 65
```

and so on.

When `k` is equal to `10` then nothing is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

When `main` evaluates `out(5)`, `out` runs and does this:

- `k` is not 10, so continue.
- Print `k`, which is 5.
- Evaluate `out(6)`.
- Print `k`, which is 5.

That evaluates `out(6)`, so replace the step “Evaluate `out(6)`” with what `out` does for that:

- `k` is not 10, so continue.
- Print `k`, which is 5.

  - `k` is not 10, so continue.
  - Print `k`, which is 6.
  - Evaluate `out(7)`.
  - Print `k`, which is 6.
- Print `k`, which is 5.

Now you can see the program is going to print 5, then 6, then evaluate `out(7)`, then print 6, then print 5. This continues until we have:

- `k` is not 10, so continue.
- Print `k`, which is 5.

  - `k` is not 10, so continue.
  - Print `k`, which is 6.

    - `k` is not 10, so continue.
    - Print `k`, which is 7.

      - `k` is not 10, so continue.
      - Print `k`, which is 8.

        - `k` is not 10, so continue.
        - Print `k`, which is 9.

          - `k` is 10, so return 1.
        - Print `k`, which is 9.
      - Print `k`, which is 8.
    - Print `k`, which is 7.
  - Print `k`, which is 6.
- Print `k`, which is 5.